# PHP Loop Not Finishing?

Tags: php, loops

I am checking our system for dead products. Because of the amount of items (100.000+ dresses), I loop through the whole DB-Table by 100.

After checking a set of 100 items, I output a message that displays the time that has passed.

**Problem**: Somehow it stops always at 2400-2500 (see below).

Do you know where the problem could be?

Maybe the increment is the problem?

Here's the code:

```
// get the amount of all rows to enable pagination later
$AllRowsResponse = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ".$targettablename." WHERE 1") or die ("Error #111231".mysql_error());
mysql_close($conn);

// write amount of rows into variable
$AllRows = mysql_fetch_array($AllRowsResponse) or die (mysql_error());
$RowCount = $AllRows["Count"];
//print "<br>all rows in table: " . $RowCount ;flush();
print "<br><h1>CHECKING ".$TargetTable." FOR DEAD PRODUCTS</h1><br>";

$deletedprods = 0; // set up counter for deleted product
$i = 0; // counter
$increment = 100; // increment steps 
$timetotalstart = microtime(true); // variable to measure each requests time. this is the beginning time
$md5deadimage1 = md5(file_get_contents("www.mydomain.com/dead1.jpg")); // get md5 of "not available" pic ONCE
$RowsMinusDeleted = $RowCount - $deletedprods; // when deleting a prod, dont look for rows that arent there anymore

while ( $i <= $RowsMinusDeleted) { // as long as the counter is below the rowcount, there are still rows to check

    $limitstart = $i;
    $limitend = $i + $increment; //MAYBE PROBLEM IS HERE???

    $conn = ConnectToDB();

    $ProductIds = mysql_query("SELECT ProductId,Image,Deeplink FROM ".$targettablename." WHERE 1 LIMIT " . $limitstart . "," . $limitend) or die ("Error #11124".mysql_error());
    mysql_close($conn);     

    $i = $i + $increment; // increase the counter by the above defined increment


    //print " DEAD-MD5:" & $md5deadimage1;flush();

    print "<br>(Checking items " . $limitstart . "-" . $limitend . "(of ". $RowCount . " total))";flush();
    //$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($ProductIds);
    //print "<br>amount of ids etc in array: " . count($rowCount) ;flush();
    $timeloopstart = microtime(true);
    // write every productId into an array
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $ProductIds ) ) {

        // get md5 of current product image
        $md5deadimage2 = md5(file_get_contents($row['Image']));
        if ($md5deadimage1 == $md5deadimage2) { // if current file md5 is equal to any "dead picture", show it/delete it 

            $deletedprods++;
            $conn = ConnectToDB();

            print "<a href=\"".$row['Deeplink']."\" target='_blank'><img src=\"".$row['Image']."\"></a>";flush();

            mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$targettablename." WHERE `ProductId`=".$row['ProductId']."") or die ("Error #11125".mysql_error());

            mysql_close($conn);
        }   
        //} // end if
        $RowsMinusDeleted = $RowCount - $deletedprods;
    } // end while
    $timeloopend = microtime(true);
    $timelooptotal = $timeloopend - $timeloopstart;
    print "<-- above took " . floor($timelooptotal) . " seconds";
}

$timetotalend = microtime(true);
$timetotal = $timetotalend - $timetotalstart;
print "<h2> whole request took " . floor($timelooptotal / 60 ) . " minutes";
print "\n<h2>Updated ".$TargetTable.". Deleted <b>".$deletedprods."</b> old products</h2>";
```

Here's what my script does:

```
CHECKING dresses FOR DEAD PRODUCTS



(Checking items 0-100(of 134902 total))<-- above took 17 seconds

(Checking items 100-200(of 134902 total))<-- above took 34 seconds

(Checking items 200-300(of 134902 total))<-- above took 48 seconds

(Checking items 300-400(of 134902 total))<-- above took 68 seconds

(Checking items 400-500(of 134902 total))<-- above took 82 seconds

(Checking items 500-600(of 134902 total))<-- above took 94 seconds

(Checking items 600-700(of 134902 total))<-- above took 109 seconds

(Checking items 700-800(of 134902 total))<-- above took 125 seconds

(Checking items 800-900(of 134902 total))<-- above took 136 seconds

(Checking items 900-1000(of 134902 total))<-- above took 146 seconds

(Checking items 1000-1100(of 134902 total))<-- above took 162 seconds

(Checking items 1100-1200(of 134902 total))<-- above took 185 seconds

(Checking items 1200-1300(of 134902 tota l))<-- above took 199 seconds

(Checking items 1300-1400(of 134902 total))<-- above took 212 seconds

(Checking items 1400-1500(of 134902 total))<-- above took 237 seconds

(Checking items 1500-1600(of 134902 total))<-- above took 277 seconds

(Checking items 1600-1700(of 134902 total))<-- above took 287 seconds

(Checking items 1700-1800(of 134902 total))<-- above took 292 seconds

(Checking items 1800-1900(of 134902 total))<-- above took 304 seconds

(Checking items 1900-2000(of 134902 total))<-- above took 305 seconds

(Checking items 2000-2100(of 134902 total))<-- above took 337 seconds

(Checking items 2100-2200(of 134902 total))<-- above took 393 seconds

(Checking items 2200-2300(of 134902 total))<-- above took 368 seconds

(Checking items 2300-2400(of 134902 total))<-- above took 375 seconds

(Checking items 2400-2500(of 134902 total))
```

Comment: your script might be timing out  - have you tried your script with set_time_limit(0);  ?

Comment: -4 down vote
 

Wahooo - Lots of code and nowhere to start.

Please stick the problem area down a bit.

Comment: Please use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: @MimiEAM: timeout could work, i will try that.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @MimiEAM: It's a pity you haven't posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Truth true, but it was late and i was already half asleep... (*excuses excuses excuses to hide the shame..*)

Comment: @truth: thanks. will replace them asap...

Answer (score 3):

Use "`set_time_limit(0)`"

More info here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Also, why are you creating a new connection to the database with every iteration? That's not necessary, just create one connection and use that.

Also a tip for troubleshooting yourself in the future, use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Hey @Evan, thanks for your reply.I will try error_reporting(E_ALL). By the way: I use a cronjob to do this job every so often. Maybe it's a problem of the cronjob also?

Comment: You can set up the cronjob to send you the output as well :)

Comment: @MimiEAM testing the timeout(0); and error_reporting(E_ALL); now...
Will report as soon as I have the results tmrw morning.